# Audio Recorder in background in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm developing an iOS app that requires to record audio continuously for hours in background.I have searched a lot on this but anything doesn't seems to work.My recorder works fine when it is in foreground but when i press the home button the recoding stops.Can anyone help me out with the code or any ideas to do so

Comment: Can open ears work in background??

Comment: can we record audio in background without jailbreak??

Comment: In iTunes there is an app named Smart Recorder-The Voice Recorder.I want to do almost the same thing.Anyone has some idea about it.

Comment: Hi Pooja, have you got any solution for background call recording?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it works for your solution to recorde audio but have a look at `iOS Background Modes`. One of these modes is called `audio`.
I have followed this [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios) to continue a file download and one section is about audio (mostly playing an audio file but maybe you can modify the code).

Maybe it also helps to solve the audio recording issue.

Comment: Yes you are right iOS supports audio in Background Modes.In info.plist i have added microphone in the background modes,but it is not working in background.I have also added applicationDidEnterBackground method.

Comment: Does iOS Simulator supports background recording?

Comment: @pooja_chaudhary I'm really not sure about the simulator. I've experienced that the different background modes behave different on the simulator (audio playing stopped but the download continued). I have not tested recording yet... To be on the save side I recommend to test such things on a real device.